# fs.mkdir not creating directory nor giving error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, fs-extra

The following code does not create a new directory, nor does it output any `err`

```js
const fs = require("fs-extra");

fs.mkdir(dirPath, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERR: When attempting to mkdir", err);
  } else {
    console.log("MKDIR made " + dirPath);
  }
  cb(null, dirPath);
});
```

I would expect the directory to be created... or an error.

When I `console.log(err)` I find that the value of err is `null`.

How can I ensure this directory has been created?

Comment: Please provide a specific directory example and tells us what exists before and after your call.  You'd likely get more traction with an answer if you provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you try the same code with `require('fs');` instead of `require('fs-extra');`?

Comment: _"Calling `fs.mkdir()` when `path` is a directory that exists results in an error only when `recursive` is `false`."_ [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) Is this the case?

Comment: I switched to ensureDir and all works fine.